# Need help for Using amazon Product Advertising API in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios5, amazon-product-advertising-api

How to use Amazon Product Advertising API to show Products inside my iPhone Application?

I have my amazon account,Secret key and necessary credentials with me But, I don't know How to create web-service for that and How to use the API.

I m referring this Link : https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html but not getting any Clear idea how to Use it.

1. If there is any Sample project or Code will be really appreciated.
2. Can user able to Buy Products through iPhone or just they can see the product detail?
3. Will Amazon allow this for Mobile device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi All  I researched a Lot  and Not finding A suitable product search API for Mobile Device From Amazon. It seems They Closed The API for Product advertisement in Mobile device.

Here is a link : http://www.zdnet.com/blog/apple/how-amazon-killed-delicious-library-for-iphone/4354

Their Official Condition : "You will not, without our express prior written approval requested via this link , use any Product Advertising Content on or in connection with any site or application designed or intended for use with a mobile phone or other handheld device." so i think we have to take Permission Before using that.

Link :  https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/agreement.html   (4.e)

I answered this Question Because i think Some One May need This And if Any One can Find Any Recent Update Or Solution Please Modify or Edit the Answer.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote Amazon Product Advertising Client https://github.com/m1entus/RWMAmazonProductAdvertisingManager

Comment: Your library looks good!  Have you had any problems from Amazon while using it?  According to this: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/apple/how-amazon-killed-delicious-library-for-iphone/4354 it's not allowed.  Thoughts?